# QR Code generator problems

Tags: php, qr-code

I am using the google chart to create a QR Code like below

```
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=http://mobile.dogoodperks.com/london/?pg=Home&couponid=<? print "$couponid&perkid=$perkid&pur=entered&city=$city"; ?>&choe=UTF-8" title="Link to Google.com" />
```

That one does not work and I even tried the one below

```
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=http://mobile.dogoodperks.com/london/?pg=Home&city=London&choe=UTF-8" title="Link to Google.com" />
```

But it did not work either please help! the qr code is generated however when scanned does not go to the page

Comment: What exactly does not work? When I browse to that url I get a valid QR-code image.

Comment: Yes the qr code is generated however when scanned does not go to the page

Comment: It does, you can verify at this url: https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx

Comment: URL is vaild : http://mobile.dogoodperks.com/london/?pg=Home

Comment: QR code and link both are working fine mobile.dogoodperks.com/london/?pg=Home

Comment: Thanks for the help the url needed some encoding and it works

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your problem is that the querystring parameters (`&city=London&..`) are not appended to the url in the QR-code.

This problem can be resolved by urlencoding the url, for example:

**Regular url**

`http://mobile.dogoodperks.com/london/?pg=Home&city=London&choe=UTF-8`

**Encoded url**
`http%3A%2F%2Fmobile.dogoodperks.com%2Flondon%2F%3Fpg%3DHome%26city%3DLondon%26choe%3DUTF-8`

In php this can be achieved using the [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)-function, for your example this would be:

```
<?php
$qr_url = "http://mobile.dogoodperks.com/london/?pg=Home&couponid=".$couponid."&perkid=".$perkid."&pur=entered&city=".$city;
$qr_url_encoded = urlencode($qr_url);
echo '<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&choe=UTF-8&chl='.$qr_url_encoded.'" />';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `echo` and `<?php ?>` in url.

```
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=http://mobile.dogoodperks.com/london/?pg=Home&couponid=<?php echo "$couponid&perkid=$perkid&pur=entered&city=$city"; ?>&choe=UTF-8" title="Link to Google.com"/>
```